# How can I retrieve the details from a SoapServerException when calling from Powershell?

Tags: web-services, powershell, soap

Whenever I make any sort of error in constructing a complex webservice call to a SOAP webservice endpoint in Powershell, I receive the cryptic & generic "SoapServerException" message.

Example:

```
Exception calling "GetListItems" with "7" argument(s): "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."
At line:1 char:1
+ $spws.GetListItems($listName, $viewName, $xmlQueryStringNodeConverted ...
```

I know there are more details to this error, but I can't view them in powershell. How can I get at them?

Comment: How about `$Error[0] | fl -Force`, `$Error[0].Exception | fl -Force` and `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException | fl -Force` right after exception occurs?

Comment: Hah. This is it, thanks. Wasn't where I expected - Powershell added the extra XML response fields to the inner exception as extra properties. I.e. $Error[2].Exception.InnerException.Detail.errorstring contains the string written below. Will update answer

Answer (score 1):

***Thanks to PetSerAI for the better answer below***

The full details of the server's response can get buried a bit, but are still accessible in ***$Error*** - specifically, webservices tend to have a "Detail" property under the innerexception, which gets added as an extra property to the $Error.Exception.InnerException.

In my case, the following printed out a much more helpful error message:

```
PS C:\> $Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Detail.errorstring.'#text'

Element <QueryOptions> of parameter queryOptions is missing or invalid.
```

---

If you are still having difficulty finding the full exception details, WireShark or Fiddler can show you the webservices server response in a friendlier format (i.e. show you the full XML, instead of manually navigating the $Error variable in Powershell).